# Force IDE - basic compile problems

Tags: salesforce

I created an Apex class and am able to deploy/download
from Salesforce Server.

I'm trying to run some code:

```
public class Class1 
{
   public void Run1() { System.debug('Run1'); } // this works
   public void Run2() { System.debug('Run2'); } // then I add this, but doesn't exist?!
}
```

In Execute Anonymous window:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.Run2();
```

"Compile error at line 2 column1
 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Class1].Run2()

When I build a project, no build status is reported
and I don't know if the build succeeded. Is there a way to confirm it worked/didn't work?
No errors/warnings are listed in the "Problems" tab. Shouldn't this be listing the errors if I enter a blatantly obvious syntax error?
Note there are small red indicator icons for syntax errors.

The Execute Anonymous method is executing old
builds of my class.  It does not recognize new
builds. Assuming my project is compiling successfully,
why doesn't the anonymous section execute the new methods?

Comment: Look for a missing dependency in your makefile, the calling source depending on the include of Class1.

Comment: Did you try to Refresh from Server option in IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some issues like those sometimes, usually caused by the IDE don't saving the files properly in the server.

The only "fix" I've found until now is cleaning the proyect, refreshing from server and checking if it has saved the changes or not.

Hope someone has a solution for this

Comment: I can't figure out what the problem is.  But yes, I have to deploy and retrieve the whole project in order to compile and run my new code.